# How to create test object of UploadedFile.class from Primefaces?

Tags: java, junit, primefaces, mockito

I need to create an instance of UploadedFile object for unit tests. I found a UploadedFileWrapper, but I still don't know how to create a correct instance of it.

Comment: `UploadedFile` is an interface and can't be instantiated.  Why not use Mockito to mock UploadedFile?

Comment: I did as You said and it works. Thanks

Comment: Isn't there by accident a similar testcas in the PF source?